# Javascript: how to add n minutes to unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a unix timestamp: 1368435600. And a duration in minutes: 75 for example.

Using javascript I need to:

1. Convert the timestamp to a string format hours:mins (09:00)
2. Add n minutes to the timestamp: timestamp + 75mins

I tried the moment.js library:

```
end_time = moment(start_time).add('m', booking_service_duration);
```

booking_service_duration was 75 but it added an hour. I'd also rather not have to use another js library

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To add 75 minutes, just multiply by 60 to get the number of seconds, and add that to the timestamp:

```
timestamp += 75 * 60
```

To convert to hours:mins you will have to do a bit more math:

```
var hours = Math.floor(timestamp/60/60),
    mins = Math.floor((timestamp - hours * 60 * 60) / 60),
    output = hours%24+":"+mins;
```

Comment: thanks, the addition works but the convertion isn't quite right - http://jsfiddle.net/Z5986/ - outputs: 380121:0

Comment: My mistake. It was 380121 hours since the unix epoch but that probably isn't very useful information. I've updated the answer to output the correct time in 24h format.

Answer (score 5):

Unix time is the number of seconds that have elapsed since 1 January 1970 UTC.
To move that time forward you simply add the number of seconds.

So once you have the minutes, the new timestamp is `oldTime + 60*minutes`
For the conversion look up parsing libraries, there is code out there for this, do some research.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to convert a timestamp you have, `timestamp`, to *locale time string* after adding some time interval, specifically minutes, to it.

Whether you have a *kind* of *date-time string* or a kind of *epoch mili/seconds*, just create a Date object:

```
const date = new Date(timestamp);
```

Keep in mind since what you need to do require to add/substract some numbers (your case: minutes) to another number, not some *date object* or some *date-time string*, and that number is the *epoch mili/secods* of your date. So, always you will need the number representation of your date in mili/seconds. JavaScript `Date.prototype.getTime()` does return *epoch miliseconds* of your date. Use it:

```
const miliseconds = date.getTime();
```

Add as many as miliseconds to it:

```
const newMiliseconds = miliseconds + (75 * 60 * 1000);
```

After that, as you said you need a *date-time string*, well a portion of it; *locale time string*, you will need to go all the way back; from numbers to date object and to a date-time string:

```
const newDate = new Date(newMiliseconds);
const newTimestamp = newDate.toString();
```

Or instead of getting the whole string of it, use the following specialized method to get the format/portion of the string representation of the date object that you like directly:

```
const newTimestamp = newDate.toLocaleTimeString(); // "12:41:43"
```

Finally, all you have to do is to just strip the last semicolon and seconds to get hours:minutes format:

```
const newHoursMins = newTimestamp.slice(0, -3);
```

Better make a function of it:

```
function timestampPlus(timestamp, milisecondsDifference, toStringFunc = Date.prototype.toString) {
  const date = new Date(timestamp);
  const miliseconds = date.getTime();
  const newMiliseconds = miliseconds + milisecondsDifference;
  const newDate = new Date(newMiliseconds);
  const newTimestamp = toStringFunc.call(newDate); // a bit advanced stuff here to let you define once and use whatever kind to string method you want to use, defaults to toString()
  return newTimestamp;
}
```

I left the final formatting out here. You can use this for substraction as well by pasing a negative second argument. Note the seconds argument is in miliseconds and *unix timestamp* varies and might given to you as seconds instead, in which case you will need to convert it to miliseconds or change the above funciton definition.

```js
function timestampPlus(timestamp, milisecondsDifference, toStringFunc = Date.prototype.toString) {
      const date = new Date(timestamp);
      const miliseconds = date.getTime();
      const newMiliseconds = miliseconds + milisecondsDifference;
      const newDate = new Date(newMiliseconds);
      const newTimestamp = toStringFunc.call(newDate); // a bit advanced stuff here to let you define once and use whatever kind to string method you want to use, defaults to toString()
      return newTimestamp;
    }
console.log("new Date(1368435600*1000).toLocaleTimeString(): ", new Date(1368435600*1000).toLocaleTimeString())
console.log("timestampPlus(1368435600*1000, 75*60*1000, Date.prototype.toLocaleString): ", timestampPlus(1368435600*1000, 75*60*1000, Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString))
```

Apart from what you need, for last parameter, `toStringFunc`, your options vary and encompasses all related `Date` methods, the are on `Date.prototype`:

1. `toString`
2. `toDateString`
3. `toTimeString`
4. `toLocaleString`
5. `toLocaleDateString`
6. `toLocaleTimeString`
7. `toIsoString`
8. `toUTCString`
9. `toGMTString`
10. `toJSON`